# If an initial value problem has a solution on $[0,a)$ for all $a>0$, will it have a solution on the whole $[0,\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

> Consider the initial value problem on $[0,\infty)$:
> $$x'(t)=f(t, x(t)) \qquad x(0)=0,\label{1}\tag{$*$}$$
> where $f:(0,\infty)\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a continuous function. Assume that for every $a>0$, there exists a $C^1$ solution $x(t)$ to the initial value problem \eqref{1} on $[0,a)$ with $x\in C([0,a))\cap C^1((0,a))$ (the solution is not necessarily unique). Can we conclude that there is a solution to the initial value problem \eqref{1} on the whole $[0,\infty)$?

This problem comes from one of my friends.

**Attempt.** I think the answer is *“no”*. To find a counter-example, I tried to construct an $f$ such that the initial value problem $(*)$ has a solution $x(t)$ on $[0,T)$ with the property $$x(t)\sim \frac1{T-t}, \qquad t\sim T-$$
for all $T>0$; and such that $(*)$ doesn't have global solutions on the whole $[0,\infty)$. However, the function $\frac1{T-t}$ doesn't take the value $0$ at $t=0$, so I considered instead
$$x(t)=\frac{\eta(t)}{T-t}, \qquad t\in[0,T)\tag{1}$$
for some good function $\eta(t)$ with $\eta(0)=0$. Now the function $(1)$ satisfies
$$x'(t)=\frac{\eta(t)}{(T-t)^2}+\frac{\eta'(t)}{T-t},\qquad t\in[0,T),$$
which impiles that $x$ is a solution to the following initial value problem on $[0, T)$:
$$x'(t)=\frac{1}{\eta(t)}(x(t))^2+\frac{\eta'(t)}{\eta(t)}x(t),\qquad x(0)=0. \tag{2}$$
However, the initial value problem $(2)$ has a trivial global solution $x\equiv0$ and many non-trivial global solutions $x(t)=\frac{\eta(t)}{C-t}$ on $t\in[0,\infty)$ for $C<0$. Therefore, **this method doesn't work**.

Any help would be appreciated!

***Note***. This problem has been [cross-posted in MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436309/if-an-initial-value-problem-has-a-solution-on-0-a-for-all-a0-will-it-hav) and has been **answered** by [Saúl RM](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/807670/sa%c3%bal-rm).

Nevertheless, more examples or comments are welcome!

Comment: For an example with exploding solutions at arbitrary times you can take a right side that behaves like $\sqrt{x}$ close to $x=0$ and $x^2$ for larger $y$. One could try $x'=\sqrt{x+x^4}$, where a solution could start as $x'^2=x+x^4$, $2x'x''=x'+4x'x^3$, so that an arbitrarily long segment with $x=x'=0$ could be followed by a segment satisfying $x''=\frac12+2x^3$. But then the zero function is a solution on $[0,\infty)$

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks for your comment! This is an interesting idea. But $x\equiv 0$ is a global solution. Can we prove that the non-trivial solution to $x''=1/2+2x^3, x(0)=x'(0)=0$ will blow up at finite time? Although it helps nothing here. I just wonder.

Comment: That would follow from the original equation, after reaching a positive $x(t_1)$ the dynamic $x'>x^2$ forces a pole in finite time.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Oh yes! Thanks! :)

Comment: Doesn't "solution on $[0,\infty)$" mean "solution on $[0.a)$ for all $a>0$"?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for your comment. Not really. "solution on $[0,\infty)$" means that the maximal existence interval of the solution is $[0,\infty)$. I want to find a example for which there does not exist a solution with maximal existence interval $[0,\infty)$, but at the same time "it has a solution living on $[0,a)$" for any finite number $a>0$ (For different $a$, the solutions may be different). Saúl RM has given an example in the [MO  post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/436313/141451).